# How to give objects clickable labels in Blend4Web?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend4web

The [Blend4Web Planetarium Demo](https://www.blend4web.com/en/demo/planetarium/) has text labels that expand to show more info when clicked. How can I make these?

Answer (score 2):

### These labels are called Anchors.

[Here](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/objects.html#anchor-settings) is the section of the Blend4Web Manual that explains about them.

[image: Blend4Web's Anchors - used for tagging and interactive annotation]

The object to be given an Anchor must be an Empty, so if you don't have an Empty selected the option will not be available in the menu.

Here's where to find the Anchor settings (for an Empty):

[image: Blend4Web Anchor properties - annotation]

The above screen shot was taken from the Planetarium Demo you mentioned. The source files are included in the Blend4Web SDK, so you can see exactly how it was done: `/blender/interactivity/solar_system/solar_system_en.blend`

Comment: how can i load data from an external html file?

Comment: @sharadgupta First, set the Anchor *Type* to "Custom Element" and for *HTML Element ID* type the name of your unique DIV ID. Then, for *Description Source* choose "File". Please familiarize yourself with [the three different methods of placing Blend4Web content on websites](https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/59/) - because I believe the "Custom Element" type does not work with Method #1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i want to know that is there any way so that when i click on my blender character a pop up window comes in front and displays data and i want to fetch that data from database and then display it?

Comment: @sharadgupta The simple answer is: Yes, you can. Because whatever is in that DIV will be displayed. However, at this point it becomes more of a web development question than a Blender question. You can have that data be generated by a PHP script, or retrieved from an SQL database, for example.