# How to use anchor in blend4web?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend4web

How can i display data on my webpage using BLEND4WEB .Is there any way so that i can fetch the data from database and then display it on my webpage using BLEND4WEB?

Comment: This may be possible using Javascript programing directly in the application, but probably not doable directly from inside the Blender GUI, but it is not really my area of expertise . Probably better ask this over at their official support site https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/

Comment: This question [is a duplicate](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54129/how-to-give-objects-clickable-labels-in-blend4web), as you know. ;-) Let's try to keep Q&A data consolidated in one place on Stack Exchange, so that it will be easier for others to find and use. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about programing for the web, and not blender or blend4web.